# How do I treat objects when having both RMI and Socket connections?

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I am in the process of creating a game using Java. It is requested of me that the player of the game can choose to connect either through a RMI connection or a Socket one. Until now I have created all the necessary components for the game, but when it comes to creating the RMI connection, i'm having a bit of problem. From what I have read in regards of RMI all the objects used to create the connection need to be declared Remote (for example implement the Serializable interface). Seeing that I have to create both types of connections, I don't see it reasonable to serialize all the objects created so far. At this point I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Create a remote version of the necessary objects for the connection(for example by creating a class that extends said object and implements Serializable interface to make the object remote). After doing that, I can define the methods applicable to the remote objects that can be invoked by the clients.
2. Create this new type of remote objects that are just messages that take the requests from the client and "translate" them to the non remote objects and then proceed to do what was requested.

I am new to Java and I would appreciate your time and patience on this question.

Comment: how were you planning on passing the data over the socket?

Answer (score 0):

> From what I have read in regards of RMI all the objects used to create the connection need to be declared Remote (for example implement the Serializable interface).

You didn't read that anywhere. It doesn't even makes sense. Implementing `Remote` doesn't make an object `Serializable`. You have to

1. Design a remote *interface* that *extends* `Remote`.
2. Ensure that every object that will be passed or returned via this interface implements `Serializable` or, in rare cases, a remote interface.
3. Write an implementation of the interface, that typically extends `UnicastRemoteObject`.

If you have any remote objects at (2), repeat.

> Seeing that I have to create both types of connections, I don't see it reasonable to serialize all the objects created so far.

You don't have any choice about (2), although that is unlikely to include all the objects created so far. In any case you would already have had to do it for objects you were planning to send over a socket.

> At this point I can think of two possible solutions:
>
> 1. Create a remote version of the necessary objects for the connection(for example by creating a class that extends said object and implements Serializable interface to make the object remote).

Again this is just nonsense.

> After doing that, I can define the methods applicable to the remote objects that can be invoked by the clients.

That corresponds to my step 1.

> 2. Create this new type of remote objects that are just messages that take the requests from the client and "translate" them to the non remote objects and then proceed to do what was requested.

This also is nonsense.